# ./a.out results '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: c++, command, command-prompt

I am very new to c++ and using the command prompt.

I have multiple .cpp and .h files that run fine on my IDE (Code::blocks) running  GNU GCC as the compiler. It displays what I need it too but when I try to use the command prompt and type "g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp ...." then "./a.out

I get the error "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
I have cygwin64 with the proper g++, cdb, make packages installed and the path setup.

what have I messed up?

Comment: the output file most likely is not executable, try `sudo chmod +x a.out`

Comment: @ChrisMc this question is about windows and command prompt. `sudo` is for linux

Comment: Could you add on the full chain of events? Delete all of the generated files and then run your build command line. Copy everything (well almost everything. The command all of the output, but not your banking records. Best if we don't see that) and paste it into the question. One of the eagle-eyed folk out here might spot something you've missed.

Comment: It looks like you're applying Linux command line instructions to a Windows command prompt.

Comment: cygwin on windows? just cd to that directory and try a.out
or you can try .\a.out

Comment: g++ on windows outputs executable a.exe. Yet another case: you got compiler errors and you hid this important information from the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *command-prompt* you just add executable filename (e.g. `out.exe`)

In *powershell* run the executable file like `.\out.exe`.

The command :

```
g++ -c [source file].cpp produces object file [source file].o
```

And The command :

```
g++ -o [executable file] [object file].o produces object file [executable]
```

For example Compiling `"hello.cpp"` into executable `"hello.exe"` in one step and running it :

> ```
> Z:\cpp> g++ -o hello.exe hello.cpp
> Z:\cpp> hello.exe
> ```

Create the `exe` file using object files :

> ```
> Z:\cpp> g++ -c file1.cpp
> Z:\cpp> g++ -c file2.cpp
> Z:\cpp> g++ -o out.exe file1.o file1.o
> Z:\cpp> out.exe
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you are following a recipe or tutorial that was designed for Unix-like systems such as Linux, but you are using Windows.

In Linux, the character `.` means the current directory, while a forward slash `/` is the directory separator. So, this:

```
./a.out
```

refers to the file named `a.out` in the current directory.

In Windows, `.` still refers to the current directory, but instead of a forward slash, a backward slash `\` is used to separate directories. So, this:

```
.\a.out
```

refers to the file named `a.out` in the current directory.

However that is still not the answer: on Linux, if you do not specify otherwise, the g++ command will produce an executable called `a.out` (strange name, but it is named that for historical reasons). Under windows, however, that is not a valid name for an executable, as Windows requires executables to end in `.exe`. As a result, if you don't specify other wise, the executable will be named:

```
a.exe
```

Yet another difference: in Windows, the path includes the current directory by default, so you do not even need to specify the `.\` on the front.